# Working with two targets that have different entry points - macos and swift

Tags: swift, macos, target

I have two versions of an app:

- bought before the user downloads
- free to download with subscriptions

With these two versions, I have created two targets in my project, a PRO version (bought at download) and a non-PRO version with subscriptions

I want to have two different entry points depending on the version, but I receive this error: "Expected declaration"

[1st entry point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeJMO.jpg)

[second entry point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pnma0.jpg)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You need the inside of your #if / #endif block to work standalone, it has to include the whole struct right to the last closing }, not just the annotation.

Comment: Please do not post code as image, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Try and use #if defined(isPROVersion) ... #endif